# Reduce square root to simplest radical form

Tags: python, beginner, python-3.x

The function `redsqrt(n)` prints out the most reduced form of the square root of *n*. It calls on another function `perfsq(n)`, which produces a list of perfect squares less than or equal to *n*.

```
from math import sqrt
def perfsq(n):  
    # Returns list of perfect squares less than or equal to n 
    l = [1]
    i, x = 0, 3
    while l[-1]+x <= n:
        l.append(l[i]+x) # Add x to get next perfect square
        i += 1 
        x = 2*i+3
    return l
def redsqrt(n):
    # Prints most reduced form of square root of n
    if n < 0:
        print('Negative input')
        return
    if sqrt(n).is_integer():
        print(int(sqrt(n))) # Square root is an integer
        return 
    # Find perfect squares that are factors of n
    l = [i for i in perfsq(n/2) if n%i==0 and i>1] 
    if len(l)==0:
        print('\u221A',n) # Square root is irreducible
    else:
        a = int(sqrt(max(l))) # Coefficient
        b = int(n/max(l)) # Argument of the square root
        print(a,'\u221A',b) # Reduced square root
```

Examples:

```
redsqrt(5.7)
√ 5.7

redsqrt(100)
10

redsqrt(2000)
20 √ 5

redsqrt(2040506)
13 √ 12074
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Style

Give your code some love and help readers by adding blank lines to separate logical sections of code. It is recommended to use two blank lines before function definition.

Space after commas and around operators also help make the code more readable.

Some of your comments would be better suited as [docstrings](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/) and some other barely state *what* you are doing, which we could read from the code already. Comment should focus on *why* instead.

Lastly using meaningful variable names play a large role in making your algorithm understandable. Avoid abreviations.

```
from math import sqrt


def perfect_square(limit):  
    accumulation_list = [1]
    index, increment = 0, 3
    while accumulation_list[-1] + increment <= limit:
        accumulation_list.append(accumulation_list[iindex] + increment)
        index += 1 
        increment = 2 * index + 3
    return accumulation_list


def reduced_sqrt(n):
    """Print most reduced form of square root of n"""

    if n < 0:
        print('Negative input')
        return

    if sqrt(n).is_integer():
        print(int(sqrt(n)))
        return 

    # Find perfect squares that are factors of n
    factors = [square for square in perfect_square(n/2) if n % square == 0 and square > 1]
    if len(factors) == 0:
        print('\u221A', n) # Square root is irreducible
    else:
        a = int(sqrt(max(factors))) # Coefficient
        b = int(n / max(factors)) # Argument of the square root
        print(a, '\u221A', b) # Reduced square root
```

## Unnecessary work

- Why compute the perfect squares starting from 1 if you are going to filter this value later on?
- Why compute all these values at all if you're only going to take the `max` of all factors?
- You also compute `sqrt(n)` and `max(factor)` several time when you could store the result in a variable.
- Most importantly, you compute the perfect squares rather expensively only to recompute its fairly expensive `sqrt` when you find one as factor.

Instead you could iterate from the nearest integer lower than `sqrt(n)` down to 1 and see if its square is a factor of `n`. Once found you have your factor without computing the remaining values. If none can be found, you know that you have an irreducible square root.

A first draft could be:

```
from math import sqrt


def reduced_sqrt(n):
    """Print most reduced form of square root of n"""

    if n < 0:
        print('Negative input')
        return

    root = int(sqrt(n))
    found = False

    for factor_root in range(root, 1, -1):
        factor = factor_root * factor_root
        if n % factor == 0:
            found = True
            reduced = n // factor
            if reduced == 1:
                # n was a perfect square
                print(factor_root)
            else:
                print(factor_root, '\u221A', reduced)
            break

    if not found:
        # irreducible square root
        print('\u221A', n)
```

## Reusability

It is bad practice to encore computation and output in the same function as it makes it harder to test and reuse. You should instead `return` a couple "coefficient/reduced square root" so that the caller can handle the logic of pretty printing the output.

This also means you need better handling of you error case. The standard in Python being to raise an exception. Here `raise ValueError('negative input')` should be enough. But you don't even need that as `sqrt` of a negative number already raise a `ValueError`:

```
>>> sqrt(-1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: math domain error
```

Lastly, returning values let you short circuit your computation and remove the need of the `found` flag:

```
from math import sqrt


def reduced_sqrt(n):
    """Return most reduced form of square root
    of n as the couple (coefficient, reduced_form)
    """

    root = int(sqrt(n))

    for factor_root in range(root, 1, -1):
        factor = factor_root * factor_root
        if n % factor == 0:
            reduced = n // factor
            return (factor_root, reduced)

    return (1, n)


def print_reduced_sqrt(n):
    coefficient, reduced = reduced_sqrt(n)
    if coefficient == 1:
        print('\u221A', reduced)
    elif reduced == 1:
        print(coefficient)
    else:
        print(coefficient, '\u221A', reduced)
```

Answer (score 2):

### General remarks

Instead of cryptic names like `perfsq` and `redsqrt`, prefer `perfect_squares` and `reduced_sqrt`.  The short names will drive you crazy when your programs get more complex.

Instead of comments like `# Returns list of perfect squares less than or equal to n`, write a proper docstring.

Consider how the outputs are to be conveyed to the caller.  `perfsq` would be simpler as a [generator](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#generators).  `redsqrt` would be better as a function that returns its result rather than printing it.

### perfsq(n)

I find the `while l[-1]+x <= n` and the `x = 2*i+3` formula hard to understand.  You just want to find the successive sums 1 + 3 + 5 + 7 + …, right?  I think that this is clearer:

```
import itertools

def perfect_squares(limit=math.inf):
    """Yield perfect squares less than or equal to the limit."""
    s = 0
    for i in itertools.count(1, 2):
        if s > limit: break
        s += i
        yield s
```

You could also go with a purely functional "one-liner", which I like because "takewhile" and "accumulate" help describe what is going on.

```
import itertools
import math
import operator

def perfect_squares(limit=math.inf):
    """Yield perfect squares less than or equal to the limit."""
    yield from itertools.takewhile(
        lambda s: s <= limit,
        itertools.accumulate(itertools.count(1, 2), func=operator.add)
    )
```

### redsqrt(n)

Printing `'Negative input'` isn't that helpful.  The function should raise a `ValueError('Negative input')`.  Better yet, just handle the situation gracefully by factoring out \$i\$.

Your algorithm is not as efficient as it could be, because it is not reducing `n` every time it finds a factor.  Consider this implementation, which reduces the search space every time any factor is found, whether it is a perfect square or not:

```
from itertools import accumulate, chain, count, groupby

def prime_factors(n):
    """
    Find the prime factors of n.

    >>> list(prime_factors(360))
    [2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 5]
    """
    for i in chain([2], count(3, 2)):
        while n % i == 0:
            yield i
            n //= i
        if i > n:
            break

def reduced_sqrt(n):
    """
    Find the most reduced form of the square root of n.

    >>> reduced_sqrt(360)
    '6 √ 10'
    >>> reduced_sqrt(-360.0)
    '6 i √ 10'
    >>> reduced_sqrt(-3.6)
    'i √ 3.6'
    """
    if not (isinstance(n, int) or n.is_integer()):
        outside, inside = 1, abs(n)
    else:
        outside = inside = 1
        for p, p_group in groupby(prime_factors(int(abs(n)))):
            p_exponent = len(list(p_group))
            outside *= p ** (p_exponent // 2)
            inside  *= p ** (p_exponent % 2)
    return ' '.join(filter(None, [
        str(outside) if outside != 1 else None,
        'i' if n < 0 else None,
        '\u221A ' + str(inside) if inside != 1 else None,
    ]))
```

Answer (score 1):

- Avoid magic numbers. Consider

  ```
      square_root_symbol = '\u221A'
  ```
- A test for `n < 0` is not enough: `n` may not even be an integer. A Pythonic way is to *ask for apology, not permission*. Try your business logic, and catch exceptions.
- Special casing `sqrt(n).isInteger()` doesn't look necessary. Consider:

  ```
      factor = perf_square_factor(n)
      if factor > 1:
          print (factor, end='')
      n /= factor * factor
      if n > 1:
          print (square_root_symbol, n, end='')
      print()
  ```